# Nokia Lumia Windows Version

Tags: operating-system, windows-phone

I'd like to open my developer activity to windows phones, Windows Phone 7 and 8. I'd like to own a test device.
The Nokia Lumia 520 appears to be really affordable, but the only OS spec available online is "Windows Phone OS".

Could someone tell me which version of Windows it is? WP7, WP8, Other?

Which cheap Windows Phone so you use to debug Windows Phone apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lumia 520 ships with Windows 8.

It is a successor to Lumia 510 which came with Windows 7.

It's a good device to test on if you want to check how the app will run on lowest commonly used hardware. However it lacks memory compared to higher end devices.

Comment: Fine ! Will I be able to debug a windows phone 7 project on Visual Basic 2010 ? If no then what should I do (windows 7 partition)?

Answer (score 2):

1. Everything is called Windows Phone (WP7 or WP8).
2. Lumia 520 (or any Lumia which is '20') is Windows Phone 8. and All WP8 are upgradable to WP 8.1
3. I'll suggest waiting for Lumia 630. It's an excellent choice at that price.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try for Nokia lumia 525 which is basically the same as Lumia 520 but with double the RAM.

I think 1 GB RAM is decent to test most applications.

The WP 8.1 update is also due soon so you'll be able to test on that version as well.

Comment: thank you for your useful answer but i'd rather like to have a common low configuration to optimize my code :)

Answer (score 0):

Nokia Lumia 520 has now upgraded to WP 8.1. I'd also recommend Lumia 520 as test device.